# Devise Routing Error in rails 3.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I've looked through all the Devise routing error discussions here and couldn't find a solution that fixes my problem. My environments are the following:
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Rails 3.2.6
- Devise 2.2.0

I followed all the steps here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

The files are:

routes.rb:

```
Dealzhunt::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :members 

  get "browse/all"

  get "home/index"

  root :to => 'browse#all'

# some other code
```

member.rb:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

rake routes:

```
          new_member_session GET    /members/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
              member_session POST   /members/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
      destroy_member_session DELETE /members/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
             member_password POST   /members/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
         new_member_password GET    /members/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
        edit_member_password GET    /members/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                             PUT    /members/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
  cancel_member_registration GET    /members/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
         member_registration POST   /members(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
     new_member_registration GET    /members/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
    edit_member_registration GET    /members/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                             PUT    /members(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                             DELETE /members(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                  browse_all GET    /browse/all(.:format)            browse#all
                        root        /                                browse#all
```

For the following URLs:

```
http://localhost:3000/members/sign_in
http://localhost:3000/members/sign_up
```

i'm getting the following error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"devise/browse", :action=>"all", :category=>0}
```

One strange symptom I observed is that if I modify root :to => 'home#index', the message is the same. I thought it would at least change to devise/home but it remained at /browse

Strangest thing is I start a new clean rails project, devise actually works. I'm wondering if it's because some error happened when I ran rails generate devise:install

Really stuck with this issue. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Does changing the order of entries in routes.rb have any meaningful effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear lord I found out the cause of the problem. Devise is having trouble with the link_to syntax. A temporary solution is to modify all the link_to to

```
<%= link_to "Home", :controller => "/browse", :action => "all" %>
```

with the / before the controller name. Here's more details on the issue: github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/471

Comment: Does changing the path of the root url fix the issues with the sign_in page?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting this error? I.e., which page are you loading?

It seems like you are having a link or something on it that routes to the controller "devise/browse" - instead, it should only route to the controller "browse". In the output generated by rake routes

```
browse_all GET    /browse/all(.:format)            browse#all
```

you will see that you apparently have a `browse` controller with an `all` method.

Comment: I'm seeing the error on http://localhost:3000/members/sign_in. It does seem like there's some configuration that routes to the controller devise/browse. Is this expected from devise?